# Weak Wifi Signal on Ubuntu wlx88835d5256de

Tags: wireless, usb, realtek-wireless

Before I tell you the story, note that I search all topics and do most of tips but I have still this problem and nothing changed.

I have very weak WiFi signal on Ubuntu . below there are some information about my system. please help me to reach WWW via WiFi on Ubuntu.

The wireless adapter is `0bda:b720 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.` connected to USB internally.

```
iwconfig
wlx88835d5256de  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
lo        no wireless extensions.



model name  : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N3350 @ 1.10GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N3350 @ 1.10GHz

   description: Motherboard
   product: A116CV20
   vendor: HOMETECH
   physical id: 0
   version: .B002
 *-firmware:0
```

`lspci -knn`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Host Bridge [8086:5af0] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Host Bridge [8086:7270]
00:00.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:5a8c] (rev 0b)
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:5a85] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2212]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:03.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Imaging Unit [8086:5a88] (rev 0b)
00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster [8086:5a98] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster [10ec:111a]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
00:0f.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Trusted Execution Engine [8086:5a9a] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Trusted Execution Engine [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:12.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SATA AHCI Controller [8086:5ae3] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SATA AHCI Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:14.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series PCI Express Port B #1 [8086:5ad6] (rev fb)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:14.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series PCI Express Port B #2 [8086:5ad7] (rev fb)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:15.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series USB xHCI [8086:5aa8] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series USB xHCI [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #1 [8086:5aac] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #2 [8086:5aae] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #3 [8086:5ab0] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.3 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #4 [8086:5ab2] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:17.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #5 [8086:5ab4] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:17.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #6 [8086:5ab6] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:17.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #7 [8086:5ab8] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:17.3 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #8 [8086:5aba] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:18.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #1 [8086:5abc] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:18.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #2 [8086:5abe] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:18.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #3 [8086:5ac0] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:18.3 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #4 [8086:5aee] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:19.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller #1 [8086:5ac2] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:19.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller #2 [8086:5ac4] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:19.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller #3 [8086:5ac6] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:1b.0 SD Host controller [0805]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SDXC/MMC Host Controller [8086:5aca] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SDXC/MMC Host Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
00:1c.0 SD Host controller [0805]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series eMMC Controller [8086:5acc] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series eMMC Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
00:1e.0 SD Host controller [0805]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SDIO Controller [8086:5ad0] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SDIO Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Low Pin Count Interface [8086:5ae8] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Low Pin Count Interface [8086:7270]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.1 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SMBus Controller [8086:5ad4] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SMBus Controller [8086:7270]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
```

lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1908:2311 GEMBIRD 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b720 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 145f:01d2 Trust 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: what does the `iwlist wlx88835d5256de scanning` command (from the `wireless-tools` package show? What does the `wireless-info` script ( https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info ) tell you?

Comment: wi-fi issues are often hardware specific. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1165497/edit) your question to include the make/model of your Wi-Fi adapter.  It would also be helpful to know what you've done so far with detailed results of your previous attempts.

Comment: wlx88835d5256de  Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 24:58:6E:A5:72:00
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Vux"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master

Comment: That doesn't tell us the make and model, I'm afraid. Please run `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" && sudo lshw | grep -A5 "Moth" && lspci -vnn | grep Network` then click [edit] to add the facts to your question. Please do not click Add Comment, please use [edit] instead. Editing tips are at https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code .

Comment: for wireless-info script, honestly I dont know what to do because I'm new with Linux

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. This will show your wireless adapter at least. We don't need your motherboard or CPU name.

Comment: And how could you try "most of tips" if you didn't do the first step: identify your wireless adapter.  All "tips" are hardware specific.

Comment: This was one command, not two.

Comment: I don't see any PCI wireless adapter. Are you asking about a USB dongle? Post output of `lsusb` then.

Comment: no its internal not a USB dongle

Comment: Anyway post `lsusb`. Sometimes they internally connect it to USB.

Comment: Here we go. It is `0bda:b720 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. ` RTL8723B

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: And kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: Linux 5.0.0-25-generic #26~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 1 13:51:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I am afraid it will be hard to do anything with this adapter. At least an easy way.